# How to Search a Spreadsheet Using Google Visualization Query - Based on Mulitple Search Criteria

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm using *Query.setQuery* in the Google visualization query script below to search through this simple [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA/edit#gid=0). The script looks though Column A for a name entered into an html input field, then matches that person's corresponding job and hours (from other columns) and returns these data to html input fields. (Thanks to forum member *WhiteHat* for the help with that!)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    document.getElementById('Search').addEventListener('click', searchSheet, false);
    searchSheet();

    function searchSheet() {
      searchName = document.getElementById('Name').value;

      var queryWORK = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA&sheet=QUERY');
      if (searchName !== '') {
        queryWORK.setQuery('select * where A = "' + searchName + '"');
  
      }

  queryWORK.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          console.log('Error in ID Validation Query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        var datatable = response.getDataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < datatable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
          document.getElementById(datatable.getColumnLabel(i)).value =
            (datatable.getNumberOfRows() > 0) ? datatable.getValue(0, i) : '';
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        chart.draw(datatable);
      });
    }
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div><label for="Name">Enter Name: </label><input id="Name" type="text" value="Bill" /></div>
<div><input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" /></div>
<div><label for="Job">Job: </label><input id="Job" type="text" /></div>
<div><label for="Hours">Hours: </label><input id="Hours" type="text" /></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

What I'm looking to do now is add another search criterion, and then have the match sent to a generic "results" html input field. The search will need to always look though the cells in column A and row 1 of the spreadsheet to find the match.

For instance, if in the first search field I enter *Janet*, and in second field I enter *Job*, I'd like *Cooking* to be returned in the "results" input field. Or say I enter *Adam* and *Hours*, then a match of *1.5* should be returned.

Cell A1 will always contain the same data ("Name"); however, there won't be a way for me to know the contents of the remaining cells in row 1 ahead of time (B1, C1, D2...) as these will change.

Any ideas??? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an asterisk to return all columns

`'select * where A = "' + searchText + '"'`

then use similar logic as before, to find the requested column

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    document.getElementById('Search').addEventListener('click', searchSheet, false);
    searchSheet();

    function searchSheet() {
      searchText = document.getElementById('Name').value;

      var queryWORK = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1HpHMfoEnPgESb2XPVCgb7XyGwRAvrq3EoQj4WHj4vhA&sheet=QUERY');
      if (searchText !== '') {
        queryWORK.setQuery('select * where A = "' + searchText + '"');
      }

      queryWORK.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          console.log('Error in ID Validation Query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        var datatable = response.getDataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < datatable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
          var field = document.getElementById('Field').value;
          if (datatable.getColumnLabel(i) === field) {
            document.getElementById('Result').value = (datatable.getNumberOfRows() > 0) ? datatable.getValue(0, i) : '';
          }
        }

        var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        chart.draw(datatable);
      });
    }
  },
  packages:['table']
});
```

```css
div {
  margin: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div><label for="Name">Enter Name: </label><input id="Name" type="text" value="Bill" /></div>
<div><label for="Field">Field: </label><input id="Field" type="text" value="Job" /></div>
<div><input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" /></div>
<div><label for="Result">Result: </label><input id="Result" type="text" /></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much WhiteHat...again! I spent several hours yesterday trying to get that to work. Can I buy you a beer?