# Customisable scatter google chart code with a search bar to filter results. Is a dashboard needed?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Beginner here, I am new to Javascript code and have tried to learn Google visualisations from the documentation that Google provide but I am struggling to get to grips with it.

I am trying to create a customisable google scatter graph with the data imported from this spreadsheet 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2eZztlcZCCwIrlrYowU6aC3LpD10qDNWwZ9SbtPUxU/
and use the 3rd column as a tooltip (the names).

With this, I would then like to add a search bar to live search the results. For example, searching "Steve" will only show his co-ordinates on the graph.

Is this possible and will I need a dashboard to do it?
Also what is the basic html/javascript required to get the chart? The google documentation explain the customisation of the tooltip well but only when you are inputing data directly into the code rather than importing from a spreadsheet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need a dashboard, or htmlservice and a charts library

Comment: take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38636263/5090771), similar to question, search spreadsheet and return results using google-vis...