# How to query google spreadsheet to create a google charts

Tags: google-sheets, google-api, google-visualization

I want to create a simple web-app which query my google spreadsheet and make a column graph of matching query. I can make a column graph out of my spreadsheet **[like this][1]** which obviously plotting the whole sheet. I want to place a search box on the same page to query the first column of my spreadsheet. Finally I want to make chart out of my matched result. Thanks.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/prp291/cLrze1bj/
```

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38636263/5090771) which uses a Table chart, could be easily changed to any other...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have adjusted it as per my requirement but I couldn't figure out how to draw the chart. Can you help me please. https://jsfiddle.net/prp291/z7ahgt3v/

Answer (score 2):

changed the table chart...

```
google.visualization.Table
```

to...

```
google.visualization.ColumnChart
```

and packages from...

```
packages:['table']
```

to...

```
packages:['corechart']
```

see following working snippet...

```js
 
  google.charts.load('current', {
   callback: function () {
   document.getElementById('Search').addEventListener('click', searchSheet, false);
   searchSheet();

    function searchSheet() {
      searchText = document.getElementById('Name').value;

      var queryWORK = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1y5MgFR67kn1-GHbmeIi6wuC5hmP10x4O8vAs5RWD8Sw&sheet=QUERY');
      
if (searchText !== '') {
        queryWORK.setQuery('select * where A = "' + searchText + '"');
      }

      queryWORK.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
          console.log('Error in ID Validation Query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
          return;
        }

        var datatable = response.getDataTable();
        for (var i = 0; i < datatable.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) 

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        chart.draw(datatable);
      });
    }
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


<div><label for="Name">Enter Name: </label><input id="Name" type="text" value="Search box" /></div>
<div><input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" /></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. You are awesome :)

Comment: I want to load only search box initially not the graph parameters. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to build web based charts from a Google Sheets spreadsheet is to use the RGraph connector. This way you can import the data directly into your webpage and make charts with it (this is the canvas docs page but it applies equally to the SVG charts as well):

https://www.rgraph.net/canvas/docs/import-data-from-google-sheets.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I am interested to build a web app to query spreadsheet and make the graph out of result. But your solution seems to lacking the query part.

Comment: It can fetch cells/rows/columns but nothing like an SQL query.